# in keydown event when press key(40),(38),(13) any of them, then immediately other function will stop.and current function will start

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

if i press any key of them (38)(40)(13) then immediately other function will stop.and current function will start.like if i press key(40) then function verticalSlideUp() will start.after that if i press key (38) then immediately function verticalSlideDown() will be start.and this verticalSlideUp() function will be stop.

i need help to do this.

[This is my jsfiddle.net code here](https://jsfiddle.net/Masud001/z8mstp67/)

here is my js code :

```
var allowed = true;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    allowed = !e.repeat;
}
if (!allowed) return;
allowed = false;

if (controlsEnabled)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        allowed = true;
        verticalSlideDown();
        console.log("pressed key for Down : "+e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
        allowed = true;
       verticalSlideUp();
       console.log("pressed key for Up: "+e.keyCode);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        allowed = true;
        var div= $(".scroll-inner-container");
        console.log("pressed key for stop : "+e.keyCode);
       div.stop();
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume those slide functions have some infinite loop. Maybe you can try to have some variable like `functionFired` and at the beginning of function setting some value and if that loop detects change it will break.

Comment: it would be continued as long as height would be finish. but i want to do like whenever i press key then this respective function will be start..
here my link.[jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Masud001/z8mstp67/)
here you just press 40 and 30.then you get the situation.

Comment: `$(".scroll-inner-container").stop().each(...)` seems to do the trick
https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: thank you man..! you are right..@Tom_Marulak help me to find it out.thank you very much...!